# Jenkin's Project is not triggering Automatically

Tags: jenkins, triggers, qa-c

I'm new to Jenkins, I created Python script for Auto-Trigger , If I run the python script by Manually All projects get triggered.

**For Automatic Trigger,**

I created a Project like "CVS_Jenkins", and In a Build section if i add below cmd it should trigger... but it not happening.

```
cd C:\Users\sgangadh\Desktop\PyScript

python PyScriptFile.py
```

Update1: Python code is running fine but it's not trigger the given project.

Update 2:
Below batch script codefor upload QAC report into QA-Verify,

```
qacli upload -P %a% --qav-upload --url 00.00.00.00:8080 --username XYZ --password 123 --upload-project PROJECT_NAME --snapshot-name %n%_%x% --upload-source ALL
```

Error will appear like below..

```
TimeStamp_ProjectName - file not found
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

can any one look on this, please help me out

Comment: Could you please add the source of PyScriptFile.py?

Comment: issue is not with PythonScript, Boz it's work fine.

Comment: Then where is the issue? You posted neither code nor logs. How is anybody supposed to analyse the issue?

Comment: @Michael, Can you have a look on updated question, Issue is at Batch script code it's not uploading to QA-Verify.

Answer (score 0):

First, set the error detection level on your QA-Framework project to at least 'debug'.
Then run the qacli command again, and look for an *import* or *upload log entry in your Framework section of your Users space.
That will tell you more about why the qacli command failed.